# Unity UWP build can't find AWSCredentials in the the shared credentials file in the default location

Tags: amazon-web-services, unity-game-engine, uwp

I'm making some tests (create a bucket, upload a file, list buckets etc) with Unity-UWP and Amazon AWS.

When I play it in the Editor, every thing works fine but when I try to find my AWS credentials in the UWP build it can't find them. This is my code:

```
void Start()
{
    chain = new CredentialProfileStoreChain();

    if (chain.TryGetAWSCredentials("default", out awsCredentials))
    {
        client = new AmazonS3Client(awsCredentials);
        Debug.Log("Credential OK");
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Credential NO OK");
    }
}
```

So, every time, I got "Credential NO OK" and can't continue with the tests.

**Could it be because UWP is very sandboxed and the user is not giving explicit access to the "credentials" and "config" file in the defaul location?**

**If so, what could be the solution or workaround. I wouldn't like to use my credentials in the code.**

Unity Version: 2020.3.3f1
AWS SDK: Version 3.7.38 of the netstandard2.0 DLLs
Build Environment: Visual Studio 2019
Build Type: Executable Only (for fast iteration and local test)
Build Configuration: Release
Target Architecture: x64
Test Environment: UWP running on Windows 10 Desktop, build 19041.985
Api Compatibility Level: .NET Standard 2.0

Also I added a "link.xml" file for preserving my AWS .dlls, and "internet client" anabled in both "player settings" and "appxmanifest"

thank you in advance.

Comment: `By default, the shared AWS credentials file is located in the .aws directory within your home directory and is named credentials` .. I doubt that would be the case on UWP

Comment: Yeah that's the thing, I suspect that because those files are outside the "Local folder" of my app I can't access to them... or maybe is a matter of configuration in my project setting?

Comment: Here we go again, Down voting without giving any clue, advise or critics about what it's wrong. Thanks :)

Comment: Here is the call chain i found: CredentialProfileStoreChain.cs -> SharedCredentialsFile.cs -> ProfileIniFile.cs -> IniFile.cs -> OptimisticLockedTextFile.cs -> File.Exists() & File.ReadAllText(). the last two function calls will always fail in UWP

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround for this situation, I set my credentials in the Environment variables. As this post suggest [From where and in what order does the AWS .NET SDK load credentials?](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/credential-loading-and-the-aws-sdk-for-dotnet-deep-dive), the Environment variables is one option to get the aws credentials without hard coding them.

You can lear [How to configure the Environment Variables here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-envvars.html) from the Amazon docs.

**This doesn't explain why "TryGetAWSCredentials" from the default location doesn't work on UWP** but allow me to continue with my test.

Finally my code for, e.g. list my buckets with this aproach:

```
public async void RegionCredentials()
{
    Amazon.RegionEndpoint region = Amazon.RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName("us-east-1");

    using (var client3 = new AmazonS3Client(region))
    {
        var response = await client3.ListBucketsAsync();
        Debug.Log("Region OK");

        Debug.Log("Region - Number of buckets: " + response.Buckets.Count);


        foreach (S3Bucket bucket in response.Buckets)
        {
            Debug.Log("Region - You own Bucket with name: " + bucket.BucketName);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is more a workaround rather than an answer to my question.